# How to seed the database with a many-to-many relationship in Entity Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I have a many-to-many relationship in my code and I am trying to seed the database.  Here is my seed method:

```
var loc = new List<Location> {
      new Location { LocationName = "Paradise Lane" },
      new Location { LocationName = "81st Street" }
};
loc.ForEach(l => context.Locations.Add(l));


var soft = new List<Software> {
     new Software { Title = "Adobe Creative Suite", ... Locations = loc.Single(s => s.LocationName = "Paradise Lane")}
};
soft.ForEach(s => context.Software.Add(s));
```

Here is my locations class:

```
public class Location
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string LocationName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Software> Software { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my software class:

```
public class Software
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(128)]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(10)]
        public string Version { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(128)]
        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(3)]
        public string Platform { get; set; }
        [StringLength(1000)]
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(15)]
        public string PurchaseDate { get; set; }
        public bool Suite { get; set; }
        public string SubscriptionEndDate { get; set; }
        //[Required]
        //[StringLength(3)]
        public int SeatCount { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SoftwarePublisher> Publishers { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SoftwareType> Types { get; set; }

    }
```

I am getting two errors.  One, it tells me I cannot implicitly convert string to bool.  I didn't even know I was trying to do t hat.  And two, cannot convert lambda express to delegate because soem fo the return types in the block are not implicitly convertable to the delegate return type.  Is that a reference to the iCollection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed an equals sign.  Double equals for comparing.

```
loc.Single(s => s.LocationName = "Paradise Lane")
```

vs

```
loc.Single(s => s.LocationName == "Paradise Lane")
```

Also, you can't do a `.Single()` into Locations because it is an `ICollection`.  `Single` returns 1 object, not a collection.  You should use .Where instead.  Or you can implicitly declare an array in there and use your .Single() code inside it.

Edit: Also apparently .Where() doesn't cast nicely to ICollection.  Add a ToArray and you'll get an array which is acceptable.

Comment: So you mean "loc.Where(s => s.LocationName == "Paradise Lane")"?  The compiler is complaining it needs a cast.

Comment: It's saying that an explicit conversion exists.  Is that the List of type location?

Comment: Hmm.  Try adding `.ToArray()` to the end of the `.Where()`.  Or paste the actual error text so I can try and suss it out.

Comment: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CIT.Models.Location>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<CIT.Models.Location>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) D:\Websites\CIT\CIT\Models\SampleData.cs 21 248 CIT

Comment: It builds with .ToArray();

Comment: Apparently that isn't the most performant solution.  You should do `(ICollection<CIT.Models.Location>)loc.Where(s => s.LocationName == "Paradise Lane")`

Comment: It says the number must be less than infinity.  Huh?  It is.  It's 1.  Are you sure about this?  ToArray worked fine.

Comment: Just ignore those last suggestions then and keep the ToArray

Comment: Great.  Thanks.  I've accepted your answer.  Thanks for helping me again, Malcolm.